# Style (template) assignment to menu items in Joomla 1.7 - baffled

Tags: joomla, joomla1.7, joomla-template

I have a number of Template Styles. If I change the default Style, I can see that my Styles are working. The Style actually changes. But for a week I have been trying to find out why my menu assignment doesn't work. I'm completely baffled.

So I have found two possible places where I could possibly change my Style per menu item. Either in Template Manager: Edit Style -> Menus assignment -> ticking the menu item. Or Menu Manager: Edit Menu Item -> Changing Template Style. I have tried these settings a hundred times. Those settings have absolutely no effect.

Where can I change the Style so that I get different Style for each menu item (by menu item I mean the page opened by the menu item)?

Answer (score 0):

Try to create separate style files like mymenu1style.php, mymenu2style.php etc. together with corresponding XML files as it is described at http://docs.joomla.org/Layout_Overrides_in_Joomla_1.6 in Menus section of that document
Then assign each style in Menu Manager "Edit Menu Item -> Changing Template Style"

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I didn't use the actual Joomla menus before so I didn't know what links they produce. And there was a trick in the links they produce. On Menu Manage: Edit Menu Item there is the Link for the menu item ready for copypaste. However, this link is for example:

```
index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=65
```

and the Itemid variable is missing from that! If it's missing, the template style will be the default one instead of the assigned one! So the correct link is, for example:

`index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=65&Itemid=205` (note exact cases on Itemid) (the Itemid, aka ID, is in fact also on the same Edit Menu Item page, but just separately)

Or the other correct link is, after enabling Global Configuration / Site / SEO Settings / SEF URLs Yes:

http://site.com/index.php/menualias

That would also render with the assigned template. Or without the **index.php/** part with the URL rewriting option.

So, which overrides which: the Edit Menu Item / Template Style setting or the Template Manager: Edit Style Menus assignments? The answer is, according to my test, if you keep the EMI Template Style as **- Use Default -**, then you can change it from Menus assignments. In other cases, the last saved situation overrides. If you have EMI Template Style set to **mystyle1** and Menus assignments the same page is set to **mystyle2**, the latter will override while the EMI Template Style remains set to **mystyle1**. So it's a bit confusing. Then if for the page you change EMI Template Style to **mystyle3**, that will blank out the Menus assignments setting and therefore override that.